# LDAP: Enumerate Organizational Unit users

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to list all users located in an Organizational Unit within a domain using LDAP ([`DirectorySearcher class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx)).

The domain I'm connecting to isn't the current domain, and the OU I'm trying to look at is in a very deep path with some of the OU names repeated elsewhere, e.g.:

> **MyDomain.LOCAL**/MyCompany/Clients/Contoso/Financial Site/Financial Services/**Users**

I'm able to list all users within the domain with the following code:

```
// Build the directory entry
var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(_ldapServer, _domain + "\\" +
    _systemUser, _systemPassword);
try
{
    // Bind to the native AdsObject to force authentication of the system user.
    // It will throw an exception if this is an invalid account
    object obj = directoryEntry.NativeObject;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception("Error authenticating system user. " + ex.Message, ex);
}

// create a directory searcher for that OU  
DirectorySearcher users = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);

// set the filter to get just the users
users.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=Person))";

// add the attributes you want to grab from the search
users.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName");
users.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
users.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail"); 
users.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name"); 

// grab the users and do whatever you need to do with them
var allFound = users.FindAll();
foreach (SearchResult oResult in allFound)
{
    // etc
}
```

This works, and grabs a huge list of all the users that are located in the root (domain).
However, I wish to get the users under the specific OU.

I have tried the following line:

```
var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(_ldapServer +
    "/ou=MyCompany/Clients/Contoso/Financial Site/Financial Services/Users",
    _domain + "\\" + _systemUser, _systemPassword);
```

And I get the error:

```
Error authenticating system user. An operations error occurred.
```

Does anyone know how I be more specific in the `DirectorySearcher` for the OU I'm interested in?

---

### SOLVED!

The final path string (for my example) should be the following (without the line-breaks):

```
LDAP://DomainControllerServer/OU=Users,OU=Financial Services,
    OU=Financial Site,OU=Contoso,OU=Clients,OU=MyCompany,
    DC=MyDomain,DC=LOCAL
```

```
DomainControllerServer = IP address in my case.
-- FQDN: MyDomain.LOCAL - Period-separated into DC={part} list
 |-- OU: MyCompany
   |-- OU: Clients
     |-- OU: Contoso
       |-- OU: Financial site
         |-- OU: Financial Services
           |-- OU: Users
```

Remember to escape invalid characters with a backslash (`\`), such as any of the following: `+ , \ = /`.

This was a nightmare, but thankfully it works now.

Comment: I'm using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050043/ldap-query-for-all-users-in-sub-ous-within-a-particular-ou as a starting point for browsing the OU 1 level at a time, and hopefully I'll get this working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path you gave for the Users OU is not a valid LDAP path. The LDAP path is constructed in the opposite direction compared to file system path or network path as you entered. your path may look as follows: 
ou=Users,ou=Financial Services,ou=Financial Site,ou=Contoso,ou=Clients,dc=MyCompany

The prefixes are really important (i.e. ou= or dc=) and the path I provided may be incorrect if any of the objects is of a different class.

I recommend that inside the loop of your original code sample, print the oResult.Path and copy-paste the desired path. This way there will be no errors in constructing the LDAP path.

Comment: That's *almost* how I've got it working, +1 for sure. But there's a key step missing from the path string which I found to work last night at 1min to 5pm! The final path string I used is: `LDAP://DomainControllerServer/OU=Users,OU=Financial Services,OU=Financial Site,OU=Contoso,OU=Clients,OU=MyCompany,DC=MyDomain,DC=LOCAL`

Comment: I'll tick you as answer as you're 100% right, but I'm going to edit my question to show how it should work for other people in the future. Hopefully someone else will find this question useful!

Comment: "The LDAP path is constructed in the opposite direction" Thank you for this I was so confused why I was getting a does not exist error.